Asalamualaikum wa rahmatulahi wa barakatu
My question is can we pray Salah if we have weared socks ?? Is it valid to pray salah with socks or shoes ??
Jazakallah Khair

With socks, yes; with shoes, it depends:

Your big toe should touch the ground during prostration (unlike the
forehead, which must touch the bare ground in Shia fiqh; the big
toes, knees, and palms can rest on the ground even with a cloth or
something in between them and the ground). Therefore, shoes might be
problematic unless they are sock-like in covering the toes, ensuring
that your big toes can touch the ground.
If it would be harmful to take off your shoes, such as in very cold
weather that might hurt your feet, then it is permissible to pray
with shoes on. However, you should still take care of Tahr (purity),
and the shoes should be clean (I’m not entirely sure about this
latter point regarding cleanliness, so it’s best to consult a
scholar in this regard).

